# How to start multiple Processes in Contiki to create load on CPU

Tags: c, contiki, contiki-process

How can I start multiple processes in parallel to create a congestion in CPU usage? Below is the code I was trying:-

```
#include "contiki.h"
#include <stdio.h>

PROCESS(cpu_load_process_1, "CPU Loading Process 1");
PROCESS(cpu_load_process_2, "CPU Loading Process 2");
PROCESS(cpu_load_process_3, "CPU Loading Process 3");
PROCESS(cpu_load_process_4, "CPU Loading Process 4");

AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&cpu_load_process_1);
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&cpu_load_process_2);

PROCESS_THREAD(cpu_load_process_1, ev, data)
 {
   PROCESS_BEGIN();
   PROCESS_END();
 }
 PROCESS_THREAD(cpu_load_process_3, ev, data)
 {
  PROCESS_BEGIN();
  PROCESS_END();
 }
```

but, this gives error as following:-

```
/home/user/contiki-3.0/core/./sys/autostart.h:48:24: error: redefinition of ‘autostart_processes’
struct process * const autostart_processes[] = {__VA_ARGS__, NULL}struct process * const autostart_processes[] = {__VA_ARGS__, NULL}
```

Please guide me through. Any alternative way/suggestion of creating CPU congestion would also be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Behind the macro [`AUTOSTART_PROCESSES`](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/core/sys/autostart.h), a structure definition is hidden.

```
#define AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(...)                    \
    struct process * const autostart_processes[] = {__VA_ARGS__, NULL}
```

By calling twice `AUTOSTART_PROCESSES`, you define the structure twice.

**Solution:**

Given the macro parameters, I guess that you should write:

```
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&cpu_load_process_1, &cpu_load_process_2);
```

Instead of

```
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&cpu_load_process_1);
AUTOSTART_PROCESSES(&cpu_load_process_2);
```